# How to get Action information from RouteData?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm using following code to get the controller/action information from RouteData

```
RouteData route = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(httpContext);
string controller = route.GetRequiredString("controller");
string action = route.GetRequiredString("action");
```

But should I change the string "controller" in case that the route map in Global.asax.cs does not have a part with "controller" as follows:

```
            routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{NOTCONTROLLER}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Your route data will always have "controller" key. If you look at the route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   "Default",                         // Route name
    "{NOTCONTROLLER}/{action}/{id}",  // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
);
```

What gets returned by `RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData` comes from `controller = "Home"`, not from `"{NOTCONTROLLER}/{action}/{id}"`. When you register a route, whatever is in braces gets mapped to parameter with the same name in the action, except for `{controller}` and `{action}` which specify a controller or an action on the fly. Have a read on MVC routing in more detail [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs).

To play around with routes and to understand how they work, have a play with [Phil Haack's route debugger](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/03/13/url-routing-debugger.aspx). It's invaluable if you are stuck in a situation where you just can't work out how the route works.